# How does React NPM NodeJS processes JSX Files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm a newbie to React, so please take it easy. While following the react tutorial, I find that React uses JSX and these files are detected and compiled by NPM (Node.JS). The following command creates a watch on the 'www' folder.

```
npx babel --watch www --out-dir . --presets react-app/prod
```

So I tried dropping a JS file 'like_button.js' which has JSX into my 'www' folder. The NPM Command line tool detects while outputting the following:

```
www\like_button.js -> like_button.js
```

But nothing happens. I thought it will compile it into something else? What am I suppose to expect here?

Comment: Depends on your watching configuration, it may only be looking for JSX files (that is, files with the `.jsx` extension). They don't actually look _inside_ the files for JSX. That's why if a file has JSX in it, even though you _can_ name it `.js`, you should appropriately name it `.jsx`. Always use correct file extensions.